# AngularJS: Cannot send POST request with appropiate CORS headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angularjs, cors

I'm creating a web app using **AngularJS**. To test it, I'm running the app in a **NodeJS server**, using [angular-seed template](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed).

In this app, I need to **send a JSON message to another host**, via POST request, and get the response, so, I'm using [**CORS**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).

My request is done by implementing a service that uses [**AngularJS http service**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#post) (I need the level of abstraction that $http provides. So, I don't use [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource)).

Here, my code. Please pay attention to the fact that **I modify $httpProvider to tell AngularJS to send its requests with the appropriate CORS headers**.

```
angular.module('myapp.services', []).

  // Enable AngularJS to send its requests with the appropriate CORS headers
  // globally for the whole app:
  config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
          $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;

          /**
           * Just setting useXDomain to true is not enough. AJAX request are also
           * send with the X-Requested-With header, which indicate them as being
           * AJAX. Removing the header is necessary, so the server is not
           * rejecting the incoming request.
           **/
          delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
      }
  ]).

  factory('myService', function($http) {
    return {
      getResponse: function() {
        var exampleCommand = JSON.stringify({"foo": "bar"});

        // This really doesn't make a difference
        /*
        var config = {headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        };
        */

        //return $http.post(REMOTE_HOST, exampleCommand, config).
        return $http.post(REMOTE_HOST, exampleCommand).
          success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              console.log(data);
              return data;
          }).
          error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            return {'error': status};
          });
      }
    }
  });
```

The problem is I can't make it work. I always get this **error message**:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at REMOTE_HOST. This can be fixed by moving the
>   resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

But if I do a simple jQuery AJAX call like this:

```
$.ajax(REMOTE_HOST,
{
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    data: exampleCommand,
    success: function(data) { console.log(data); },
    error: function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log("error " + textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);}
 });
```

It works fine.

So, my questions:

**- How do I allow cross-site requests in an AngularJS running under NodeJS?**

**UPDATE**: Thanks to Dayan Moreno Leon's response.

My problem is I need to [add cors support to my server](http://enable-cors.org/server.html). I'm using [**NodeJS http-server**](https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server/issues/43) for development and **lighttpd** for production.

**- Why does the simple jQuery POST request work but AngularJS POST request doesn't?**

I guess jQuery AJAX requests are [cross-domain](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) by default. Not really sure yet.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry for the simplistic comment but can you not just use JSONP?

Comment: @Chris the problem with JSONP is that you need to implement a specific logic for it, meaning tou have to tell your server to build a js response and wrap de response inside a callback function call, which makes it very jsonp specific, so you won't be able to reuse that in non jsonp calls, besides it is limited to json unless you implement your own response callback parser function. using cors is way mor consisten and clean in both server and client, might look like a pain in the b.. at first but it will save you a lot of time and effort when sharing resources

Comment: There is no such thing as `useXDomain` in Angular. It never made into the Angular code. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2956

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CORS is not handled on the client but in the server you need to allow CORS on your nodejs app where your angular app is trying to POST. you can try using cors module if you are using express

https://www.npmjs.org/package/cors

other whise you need to check for the options method and return 200 as a response

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: I'm not using express. So, do I need to previously send an OPTIONS request, get the 200 status response and then send the POST request? Because I think the high level $resource service automatically does it, but I can't use it here.

Comment: no, you don't need to do anything, thats all handled by the browser, your client side code remains the same no matter the origin, the POST,PUT, and DELETE are complex requests so the browser first issues an options request, and when it receives the go ahead (200) it sends the actual request, but for that to work your server needs to be able to respond to complex requests aswell
check this post http://annasob.wordpress.com/2012/01/11/getting-around-cors-with-node-js/

Comment: Ok. I see the OPTIONS request sent in the browser console. Sorry, I read too fast. I need to modify the server. But I'm really using Node http-server app (https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server). I don't know how to configure it. Maybe I could change to lighttpd (the production server)

Comment: Not working yet. But I think I'm close. I updated the question

Comment: did you check out the post i linked in my last comment?

Comment: Yes, I did it. Basically, the solution is to create a "proxy" server in your dev machine to catch the local request and then create a client using the domain of the backend, to re-send that request. And I guess this could be avoided if REMOTE_HOST had CORS enabled.

Comment: Anyway, your response is correct. Just a last question: why does the $.ajax request work? My bet is this request is really using JSONP.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does the simple jQuery POST request work but AngularJS POST request doesn't?

jQuery uses [simple requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests) while AngularJS uses [preflighted requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests)

In your angular code you can add set `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and encode your data using `$.param`