# Error -1 send parameters using $http.post angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a problem when you submit parameters using $ http.post in angular.

I assume it's some sort of error itself have little knowledge of angular , because in jquery work fine.

Request **jquery'javascript**

```
var user = $('#usuariotxt').val();
var pass = $('#passwordtxt').val();

var login= {
              Usuario : user,
              Password : pass
       };

       $.ajax({

          type: 'POST',
          url:  'http://190.109.185.138/Apipedro/api/login',
          data: login,
          datatype: 'json'

        }).done(function(data) {

                console.log(data);
        });
```

Request **Angular-Javascript**

```
var app;

app = angular.module('AppUPC',[]);

app.controller('Formulario',['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http){

    $scope.login = function(){

        var login = {
            Usuario: $scope.usuariotxt,
            Password: $scope.passwordtxt
        };

        console.log(login);

        var url, method;
        url = 'http://190.109.185.138/Apipedro/api/login';
        method = 'POST';


         $http.post("http://190.109.185.138/Apipedro/api/login", {}, 
                    {params: {Usuario:$scope.usuariotxt, Password:$scope.passwordtxt} 
         }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.persons = data;
                console.log($scope.persons);

        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.status = status;
                console.log($scope.status);
        });

     };

}]);
```

I have also used many other forms , including the most common

```
 $http({

            url: url,
            method: method,            
            data: login,
            headers :{'Content-Type':'application/json'}

         })
```

Errors that occur to me are the following

[image]

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083329/angularjs-cannot-send-post-request-with-appropiate-cors-headers

Comment: Is your API actually expecting a JSON payload in the request body? Your jQuery example will send `Usuario=user&Password=pass` whereas the Angular version will send `{"Usuario":"user","Password":"pass"}`. It sounds like your API is **not** set up to handle CORS pre-flight (ie `OPTIONS`) requests and the header `Content-Type: application/json` makes it a non-simple request, thus triggering a pre-flight request

Comment: Strange that it works for jquery.
It seems like a server decline for that request.
Before any request the browser sending an options type request to check if the request method is allowed by the server.
In this case the server responded with declined.

Comment: @Dvir it's not strange at all. The jQuery POST request is a *simple request* and thus would not trigger a pre-flight `OPTIONS` request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: If you want to send the same data as the jQuery example, use this

```
app.controller('Formulario', ['$scope', '$http', '$httpParamSerializer', function ($scope, $http, $httpParamSerializer) {

    // snip

    $http.post(url, $httpParamSerializer(login), {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).then(function success(response) {
        $scope.persons = response.data;
    }, function error(response) {
        $scope.status = response.status;
    });
}]);
```

This is because jQuery by default sends `POST` data as an `x-www-form-urlencoded` string, ie

```
Usuario=dfvides&Password=dfvids
```

Using the code above, Angular will send an identical request to jQuery.

Angular by default sends POST data as JSON with the `Content-Type` header set to `application/json`, ie

```
{"Usuario":"dfvides","Password":"dfvids"}
```

Is your API even set up to handle a JSON payload?

---

The reason your Angular version was triggering a [pre-flight `OPTIONS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) request (which it appears that your API is **not** equipped to handle) was because the header `Content-Type: application/json` makes the request [non-simple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests)...

> A simple cross-site request is one that:
>
> - Only uses `GET`, `HEAD` or `POST`. If `POST` is used to send data to the server, the `Content-Type` of the data sent to the server with the HTTP POST request is one of **`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`**, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain`.
> - Does not set custom headers with the HTTP Request (such as `X-Modified`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the information. For what reason is x-www accepted by def in compare to app/json?

Comment: Thank you very much , I really appreciate your help , works perfectly , thanks again, you know any tutorial explaining angular to start well .

Comment: @Dvir lack of foresight would be my guess. Even adding an `Authorization` header causes a CORS request to become non-simple which is a huge pain

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales plenty of good information in the Angular guide / docs as well as their example *PhoneCat* app